# Old Angular 2 project - successfull production build has javascript runtime errors

Tags: angular

I have a pretty old Angular 2 project. Angular CLI 1.3.1 (while the newest version at the moment is 6.2.3).

I can successfully build the project for both development and production.

Development runs great.

Production version has javascript runtime errors that seem to be due to bad uglification:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined
>       at Object.oxwE (vendor.a1c77430ed052dea4a8f.bundle.js:1)
>       at n (inline.929671279f1ce76b75d9.bundle.js:1)
>       at Object.+nms (vendor.a1c77430ed052dea4a8f.bundle.js:1)
>       at n (inline.929671279f1ce76b75d9.bundle.js:1)
>       at Object.cDNt (main.df67f626aab78f9b8645.bundle.js:1)
>       at n (inline.929671279f1ce76b75d9.bundle.js:1)
>       at Object.0 (main.df67f626aab78f9b8645.bundle.js:1)
>       at n (inline.929671279f1ce76b75d9.bundle.js:1)
>       at window.webpackJsonp (inline.929671279f1ce76b75d9.bundle.js:1)
>       at main.df67f626aab78f9b8645.bundle.js:1"

This is a new issue, it used to work in the past.

I tried to disable uglify by adding --build-optimizer=false:

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/backoffice/ --build-optimizer=false
```

According to these docs:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/1-x-build

It seems to have zero effect on the build result.

It would've been amazing to upgrade the project to the newest angular version, but it was built on top of a template that has many dependencies I'm not familiar with, which are doubtfully properly maintained. After a few hours of errors with those dependencies I gave up on that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disable AOT with the following cmd:

`ng build --prod --base-href=/backoffice/ --aot=false`

This is a way that I think worth a shot.

As my personal experience tells me every time Angular has production build error, it's 95% related to AOT.

For this legacy Angular 2 project, I guess you don't have to stick with that since it's a very old project anyway.